# Application successfully installed but not starting on emulater

Tags: android

Here i am placing the console details ,i need to change any emulator settings or need to add any statements in manifest file .help me ,thank you

```
 [2013-03-28 11:08:29 - Lisnx] Android Launch!
    [2013-03-28 11:08:29 - Lisnx] adb is running normally.
    [2013-03-28 11:08:29 - Lisnx] Performing com.lisnx.activity.SplashActivity activity launch
    [2013-03-28 11:08:34 - Lisnx] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_4.0'
    [2013-03-28 11:08:45 - Lisnx] New emulator found: emulator-5554
    [2013-03-28 11:08:45 - Lisnx] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
    [2013-03-28 11:10:49 - Lisnx] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
    [2013-03-28 11:10:49 - Lisnx] Uploading Lisnx.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
    [2013-03-28 11:11:00 - Lisnx] Installing Lisnx.apk...
    [2013-03-28 11:12:43 - Lisnx] Success!
    [2013-03-28 11:12:43 - facebook_y] Could not find facebook_y.apk!
    [2013-03-28 11:12:43 - Lisnx] Starting activity com.lisnx.activity.SplashActivity on device emulator-5554
```

Comment: Considering that you get abusive and use derogatory words and statements, I am not editing this question. Instead merely pointing out the mistakes. Use I instead of i. Punctuation should have a ` ` after not before. Read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install the facebook sdk into the emulator before your app will run.

Try this:

```
adb install %HOMEPATH%\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1\bin\FBAndroid-2.1.apk
```

Extracted from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)  section #2